# Weak continuity in Sobolev Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, sobolev-spaces, normed-spaces

First consider the following two Sobolev Embedding Theorems.

> **Theorem 1**:
>
> The continuous embedding $W^{1,p}(\Omega) \subset L^{p^{*}}(\Omega)$ holds  provided the exponent $p^{*}$ is defined as $p^{*} := \{ \frac{np}{n-p} \text{ for } p <n, \text{ an arbitrary large real for } p=n, + \infty \text { for } p>n \}$
>
> **Theorem 2(Rellich, Kondrachov Theorem)**:
>
> The compact embedding $W^{1,p}(\Omega) \Subset L^{p^{*}-\epsilon}(\Omega)$ for $\epsilon \in (0,p^{*}-1]$ holds for $p^{*}$.

Consider a bounded continuous mapping $f$:

$f: L^{p^{*}-\epsilon}(\Omega) \times L^{p}(\Omega;\mathbb{R}^{n}) \rightarrow L^{p'}(\Omega;\mathbb{R}^{n})$      $\text{             where } p^{'}=\frac{1}{p-1}$

How does it follow then that we can state that:
$f: W^{1,p}(\Omega)\times L^{p}(\Omega;\mathbb{R}^{n}) \rightarrow L^{p'}(\Omega;\mathbb{R}^{n})$ is (weak $\times$ norm, norm) -continuous?

Thanks for assistance. Let me know if something is unclear.

Comment: Is $f$ a linear function? What is in between $L^{p^\star-\epsilon}$ and $L^p$ in the product above?

Comment: $f$ is not necessarily linear. There is nothing in between the product, sorry was a mistake. Editing it now. But if you think the problem resolves easier if $f$ is linear then I would be interested in how that works. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by weak $\times$ norm?

Comment: If by (weak $\times$ norm, norm) you mean the product norm $W^{1,p}(\Omega) \times L^p(\Omega; \mathbb{R}^n)$ then the result follows from Theorem 1...

Comment: By 'weak x norm' I mean that it is the product topology where $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ is endowed with it's weak topology and $L^{p}$ is endowed with it's norm topology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $w_\alpha=(x_\alpha,y_\alpha)$ is a [net](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_%28mathematics%29) in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)\times L^p(\Omega:\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that $w_\alpha\to w=(x,y)$. We need to prove that $$f(w_\alpha)\to f(w)\tag{1}$$

We have that $x_\alpha\to x$ in the weak topology of $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$. Once Theorem 2 is valid, we can conclude that $x_\alpha \to x$ in the strong topology of $L^{p^\star-\epsilon}(\Omega)$, hence, as $f$ is continuoous with respesct to norm$\times$norm topology, we conclude that $(1)$ is true.

Remark: there is a assumption in my proof which must be verified.

Comment: Thanks for the response, how do you get weak convergence in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ implies strong convergence in $L^{p^{*}-\epsilon}(\Omega)$ from Theorem 2? And what assumption are your referring to?

Comment: This is part of the assumption I left to you verify. Try to understand it first, then if you need some help, post a comment here.

Comment: Okay I see, I will revise it and then comment if I have further queries,thanks.

Comment: There is a lemma which states 'Let $X$ be a topological space and $(x_{n})_{n}$ be a sequence in $X$ and $x \in X$. If every subsequence of $(x_{n})_{n}$ has a subsequence converging to $x$, then $x_{n} \rightarrow x$'

Comment: So if we consider $(x_{\alpha})_{\alpha}$ as a sequence then:  $x_{n} \rightharpoonup x$ weakly in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ by assumption. But by Thm 2 we have $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ is compactly
embedded in $L^{p^{*}-\epsilon}(\Omega)$ therefore there exists a subsequence $(x_{n_{j}})_{n_{j}}$ which converges in $L^{p^{*}-\epsilon}(\Omega)$
but this too is a sequence in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ $\therefore$ there exists a subsequence of the subsequence which converges in $L^{p^{*}-\epsilon}(\Omega)$,
so by the lemma above it follows that $x_{\alpha} \rightarrow x$ strongly in $L^{p^{*}-\epsilon}(\Omega)$.

Comment: Not sure if this works when considering $(x_{\alpha})_{\alpha}$ as a net, what do you think?

Comment: The same argument also work for nets. Note that every net in a compact set has a convergent subnet.